# Pass multiple column names as input to the parameter index_col using the function dask.dataframe.read_sql_table to create a dask dataframe

Tags: python, sql, dask

With this I get `ValueError`:

```
import dask as dd 
data1 = dd.read_sql_table('TABLE', connection_string, index_col = ['DATE','ITEM'],schema= 'CRE') gives me a value error --> ValueError: Use label when passing an SQLAlchemy instance as the index
```

When I just use date as shown below I am able to pull the data into a `dask dataframe`.

```
data1 = dd.read_sql_table('TABLE', connection_string, index_col ='DATE',schema= 'CRE')
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that dd.read_sql_table needs one index column on which to split your data.  Ideally this column is indexed in your SQL database so that it is easy to partition/shard.

Once you have read the data into a Dask dataframe you can then do other operations on it.  However, please not that as of 2020-06-27 Dask dataframe does not support multi-indexes.